# How to install missing dependencies of a custom Debian package?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

A custom Debian package has this dependency in the Debian control file:

```
Depends: docker-ce (=17.03.2~ce-0~debian-stretch)
```

That must be downloaded from `download.docker.com` as it isn't part of the official Debian repositories.  The apt sources list looks like this:

```
# cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
deb https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch stable
```

Installing that custom Debian package fails:

```
# dpkg --install --force-depends foo.deb
Selecting previously unselected package foo.
(Reading database ... 15743 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack foo.deb ...
Unpacking foo (0.0.0-1) ...
dpkg: foo: dependency problems, but configuring anyway as you requested:
 foo depends on docker-ce (= 17.03.2~ce-0~debian-stretch); however:
  Package docker-ce is not installed.
Setting up foo (0.0.0-1) ...
# apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  foo
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I thought `apt --fix-broken` would install the missing `docker-ce` package from the third-party repository, but instead it wants to remove my `foo` package.  The following works:

```
# apt-get install docker-ce=17.03.2~ce-0~debian-stretch
# dpkg --install foo.deb
```

What I have tried so far:

```
# apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=true install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies...Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Investigating (0) foo:amd64 < 0.0.0-1 @iU mK Nb Ib >
Broken foo:amd64 Depends on docker-ce:amd64 < none | 5:18.09.2~3-0~debian-stretch @un uH > (= 17.03.2~ce-0~debian-stretch)
  Considering docker-ce:amd64 0 as a solution to foo:amd64 2
  Removing foo:amd64 rather than change docker-ce:amd64

# apt install --assume-yes $PWD/foo.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'foo' instead of '/src/foo.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 foo : Depends: docker-ce (= 17.03.2~ce-0~debian-stretch) but 5:18.09.2~3-0~debian-stretch is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

# apt-cache policy docker-ce
docker-ce:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5:18.09.2~3-0~debian-stretch
  Version table:
     5:18.09.2~3-0~debian-stretch 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
     5:18.09.1~3-0~debian-stretch 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
     5:18.09.0~3-0~debian-stretch 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
     18.06.3~ce~3-0~debian 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
     18.06.2~ce~3-0~debian 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
     18.06.1~ce~3-0~debian 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
     18.06.0~ce~3-0~debian 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
     18.03.1~ce-0~debian 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
     18.03.0~ce-0~debian 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
     17.12.1~ce-0~debian 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
     17.12.0~ce-0~debian 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
     17.09.1~ce-0~debian 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
     17.09.0~ce-0~debian 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
     17.06.2~ce-0~debian 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
     17.06.1~ce-0~debian 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
     17.06.0~ce-0~debian 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
     17.03.3~ce-0~debian-stretch 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
     17.03.2~ce-0~debian-stretch 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
     17.03.1~ce-0~debian-stretch 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
     17.03.0~ce-0~debian-stretch 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
```

Comment: There are several ways to solve that. One of them is creating your internal repo, and letting APT deal with the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

To install a `.deb` package while downloading dependencies from the configured repositories, use

```
# apt install ./foo.deb
```

Do provide a path even if the file is in the current directory.

If the dependency still isn't found, show us the output of `apt-cache policy docker-ce`.

Comment: Using `apt install` instead of `dpkg --install` doesn't help. I've added the output of `apt-cache policy`.

Comment: @G.Fiedler Looks like you must dig further. Try installing with `dpkg` (it will error out due to the missing dependency), then issue `aptitude install -f`. It will try harder to solve the problem than `apt-get` does and hopefully give a better report at least.

Comment: `aptitude install -f` reports that either the package `foo` must be removed or the dependencies must remain unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

It is well explained in [this link](https://linuxhint.com/install_deb_packages_ubuntu/).

I know 3 different ways to do it:

a) `sudo apt install application.deb`

it will install the package it with dependencies in one run automatically:

b)

```
dpkg -i packagename.deb
```

and if there is any dependencies for the `packagename.deb`, the command below should be invoke to resolve the dependencies:

```
sudo apt install -f
```

c) `sudo gdebi my_package_1.0.deb`

if `gdebi` is not installed already, you may install it first. In order to find out if a package, like `gdebi` in our case, is installed or not, check the status of a package, you may issue the command below:

```
dpkg -s packagename
```